# Polarization of an electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, wave

How can I find polarization of an electric field as shown below?
$$\vec E (0,0,0) = \vec a_x E_{0x}+\vec a_y + 2j \vec a_z \dfrac{V}{m} $$
The propagation of the wave is as shown below.
$$ \vec a_n = \dfrac{1}{2} \vec a_x - \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \vec a _y $$

To determine the polarization of the wave, first I obtained the phasor notation.

$$ \vec E (x,y,z) = \dfrac{1}{2} \vec a_x e^{\dfrac{1}{2} \vec a_x - \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \vec a _y} +  \vec a_y e^{\dfrac{1}{2} \vec a_x - \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \vec a _y} + 2j \vec a_z e^{\dfrac{1}{2} \vec a_x - \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \vec a _y}$$

Then turn the notation to cosine representation.

$$ \vec E (x,y,z) = \dfrac{1}{2} \vec a_x cos (wt-k(\dfrac{1}{2} \vec a_x - \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2})+ \vec a_y cos (wt-k(\dfrac{1}{2} \vec a_x - \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2})+2j\vec a_z cos (wt-k(\dfrac{1}{2} \vec a_x - \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}))$$

By making $$wt = 0, \pi /4, \pi/2, \pi $$

we should be able to sense the polarization of the wave. But since the has three position vectors, I couldn't get a proper understanding.

How can I determine the polarization?

Comment: Why is there an imaginary unit \$j\$ in the E(0,0,0)? Isn't the electric field a real quantity? Does it represent 90 deg lag compared to x and y components? If so, is the polarization circular / elliptical? How did you arrive at \$a_n\$ ? Shouldn't it be normal to the electric field? Then, why doesn't it contain \$E_0\$ in it?

Comment: E(0,0,0), initial value of the E field and $$a_n$$, direction of the propagation are the given values. There is field at (0,0,0) point and propagates according to $$a_n$$.